# CORS doesn't work when request contains an email field laravel and react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cors, digital-ocean

When I make post request without email field it makes the request and return the validation messages

[image: cors work when no email field]

but when I try to send email field it gives this message `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.api/api/auth/register' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

[image: cors doesn't work]

I'm using laravel 7.0 for backend and react for frontend and using digital ocean for backend deployment.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add 'Content-Type': 'application/json' in headers when fetch the api?

Comment: yes I use `fruitcake/laravel-cors` that is shipped with laravel 7 and it enables everything also I'm using axios for requests and it works in localhost

Comment: I have ever got that.
I got that because I have several headers that didn't input and the API needs it. And I've ever used it with local, I mean, the API in local, and the Front-End in local too, and it happened too, even though I already inputted everything that needs. Then the solution at that time I'm used CORS Firefox Add-Ons for kill the CORS.